# Normalize all columns (as one) of pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, normalization

I have a dataframe in pandas were each column has a different value range. For example:

df:

```
A     B   C
1000  10  0.5
765   5   0.35
800   7   0.09
```

How would I normalize all values as they were in one column i.e.

```
A  
1000
765
800
10
5
7
0.5
0.35
0.09
```

and still keep the original dataframe structure?

Thanks!

Comment: `df.melt(value_name='A').drop('variable',1)` ?

Comment: Thanks. How do I return to the original dataframe column structure after I used melt? i.e. A,B,C columns.

Comment: dont use the drop then, `df.melt(value_name='A')` should do it? original column structure should not be kept as this is unpivotting ?